# how to call a class based template tag from views.py in Django?

Tags: django

`CoinbaseWalletAuth.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

API_KEY = '******************'
API_SECRET = '***************'


class CoinbaseWalletAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
        })
        print('hello')
        return request

register.tag('CoinbaseWalletAuth', CoinbaseWalletAuth(API_KEY,API_SECRET))
```

`Views.py`

```
def test(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
      api_url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/'
      auth = CoinbaseWalletAuth # call the class based function in views(This is not working)
      r = requests.get(api_url + 'user', auth=auth)
      data= r.json()
      return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to do here? All you've done is reference that class. And why have you made it a template tag? None of this makes any sense.

Comment: The point to use templatetags is to run somelogic while the template is rendering... in your views you already have access to write logic in python, if there some logic at your templatetag that you have to use in your application so you should write it as method (class, static or anyother) and in your templatetag call this method... so that way you can share this logic between your applcation

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question

```
from .templatetags.CoinbaseWalletAuth import CoinbaseWalletAuth

def test(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
      api_url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/'
      auth = CoinbaseWalletAuth # call the class based function in views(This is not working)
      r = requests.get(api_url + 'user', auth=auth)
      data= r.json()
      return HttpResponse(data)
```

The point to use templatetags is to run somelogic while the template is rendering... in your views you already have access to write logic in python, if there some logic at your templatetag that you have to use in your application so you should write it as method (class, static or anyother) and in your templatetag call this method... so that way you can share this logic between your applcation

in some file at your project (maybe models maybe utils)

**CoinbaseWalletAuth.py**

```
API_KEY = '******************'
API_SECRET = '***************'

class CoinbaseWalletAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key):
        ...

    def __call__(self, request):
        ...
        return request
```

**coinbase_templatetag.py**

```
from django import template
from .utils import CoinbaseWalletAuth # utils will the folder that you store that file

register = template.Library()

register.tag('CoinbaseWalletAuth', CoinbaseWalletAuth(API_KEY,API_SECRET))
```